# How to adjust X-axis point interval scale in power Bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm fairly new to Power BI. I have 2 sets of data that I want to plot on a scatter chart. The Y-axis values (Airport Layout) range from 1 - 10 while the x-axis values (Airport departures) range between 1 - 800k. When I plot this on a scatter chart with a country like the USA with a wide range of Airport departures, the intervals of the x-axis are 0, 50k, 100k 150k... which makes values between 0 and 50k on the chart harder to see.

Is it possible to create an x-axis with intervals of 0, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 and adjusts based on the values? So that the points on the chart can be more in the center.

Please see the image of my result below. I would like the values between 0 and 100k to be more in the center.

[image]